# event capture in multiple component in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-event-emitter

i have single component called address, which rendered multiple times for home address and office address, on changing one i want to update another, so that i have written sharedService and used eventemmiter. but it capturing for same component not in another ..i am expecting 'in Address' log two times

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  onMainEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
}


@Component({ ... })
export class AddressComponent {
  onMain: boolean = false;
  constructor(service: SharedService) {
    service.onMainEvent.subscribe(
      (onMain) => {
        this.onMain = onMain;
        console.log('in Address')
      }
   );
 }
updateAddress(onMain):void {
    this.service.onMainEvent.emit(onMain);
  }

}
```

Comment: A [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) repro on stacklitz.com would help us to debug this issue more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your service being injected as [singleton](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services):

for angular 6 and upper

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
   export class SharedService {
     onMainEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
   }
```

for lower:

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [UserService],
  ...
})
```

More preferred way of doing such a thing is to use flux architecture such as ngrx or ngxs for angular.

Comment: Making service singleton, Its working for me, thank you!!